# errors installing ryp2 on RHEL6 with R 3.3.3

Tags: r, rpy2, rhel6

I am trying to install rpy2 on Red Hat 6. I have upgraded to R 3.3.3 following the instructions here: https://oguya.ch/posts/2017-03-18-building-R-on-rhel-6/

When I do the rpy2 install it fails with the following:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install rpy2
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-2.8.6.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from rpy2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): singledispatch in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from rpy2)
Installing collected packages: rpy2
  Running setup.py install for rpy2 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eFwk3n/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-w5v7yg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
    /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
    /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags

        Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
            include_dirs    = ['/usr/local/lib64/R/include']
            library_dirs    = ['/usr/local/lib64/R/lib']
            libraries       = ['Rblas', 'gfortran', 'm', 'readline', 'pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'rt', 'dl', 'm']
            extra_link_args = ['-Wl,--export-dynamic', '-fopenmp', '-Wl,--whole-archive', '/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.a', '-Wl,--no-whole-archive']

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/tests_rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/indexing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/container.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/functional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_indexing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_functional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_container.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpSymbol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVector.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Sexp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpExtPtr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVectorNumeric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpEnvironment.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_EmbeddedR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpClosure.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Device.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/functions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/vectors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/environments.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/language.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/packages_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/packages.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/pandas2ri.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/numpy2ri.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/methods.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/help.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/robject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testMethods.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPandasConversions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFunction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testNumpyConversions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testArray.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testDataFrame.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testEnvironment.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testVector.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPackages.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testHelp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testLanguage.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRobjects.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFormula.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tidyr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grdevices.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/dplyr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/ggplot2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_ggplot2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_grdevices.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_dplyr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/packages.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/process_revents.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/interactive/tests
    copying ./rpy/interactive/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/interactive/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/html.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/ggplot.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/rmagic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython/tests
    copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython/tests
    copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/test_rmagic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/ipython/tests
    running build_clib
    building 'r_utils' library
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy/rinterface
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I./rpy/rinterface -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/include/Rdefines.h:36,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:23:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/include/R_ext/Memory.h:51: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/include/Rdefines.h:40,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:23:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/include/Rinternals.h:886: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    ar rc build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libr_utils.a build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
    running build_ext
    R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
    building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
    In file included from /usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:49:
    /usr/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1188:1: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
    In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:29,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:45:
    /usr/include/features.h:213:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/include/R.h:80,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/include/R_ext/Memory.h:51: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:9,
                     from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/include/Rinternals.h:886: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:64:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/include/Rinterface.h:149: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:73:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/include/R_ext/Rdynload.h:36: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c: In function ‘SexpObject_clear’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48: warning: unused variable ‘res’
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
    ./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c: In function ‘Sexp_init’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742: warning: unused variable ‘copy’
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: At top level:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203: warning: ‘PyRinterface_IsInitialized’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204: warning: ‘PyRinterface_FindFun’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:205: warning: ‘embeddedR_isInitialized’ defined but not used
    ./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2173: warning: ‘ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp’ defined but not used
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_ShowFiles’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:831: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_ResetConsole’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:677: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_FlushConsole’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:643: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_ChooseFile’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:727: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_ReadConsole’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:498: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_WriteConsoleEx’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339: warning: ‘consolecallback’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:354: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_ShowMessage’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:429: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c: In function ‘EmbeddedR_CleanUp’:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:979: warning: ‘gstate’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lreadline -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -lr_utils -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,--whole-archive /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.a(CommandLineArgs.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.a(CommandLineArgs.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eFwk3n/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-w5v7yg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eFwk3n/rpy2/
```

Anyone know what the issue is and how I can install rpy2 here?

Also tried building rpy2 from source and that failed with:

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lreadline -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -lr_utils -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,--whole-archive /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lr_utils
```

I searched and searched but did not find a place I can get libr_utils from.

Answer (score -1):

Running `pip install rpy2` will build it from source here.

Stick to `pip`, or `python setup.py install`, as indicated in the documentation. There are several connected parts when building it, and issue just one gcc command will most likely result in the errors about missing libraries (as you are seeing).

I am not sure about the error you are seeing (could be anything from antiquated C compiler to incompatible build of R or other R library). You are using a fairly old system in its "enterprise" version. May be may there will be more answers or knowledge within corporate support channels.

Comment: If installing from pip worked, I would not have needed to look for other ways. The last error (the missing lib) came from running `python setup.py install`. I did find the issue - my install of epel-release was messed up. I reinstalled that and then I was able to install R from the repos and then install rpy2 with pip. However now I am getting this error when I try and use it: `ImportError: 'No module named rpy2.robjects'`. So I have to dig into that and see what is going on.